# How to pass and use ViewBag/TempData value in partial view of mvc 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I need to use ViewBag/TempData value in partial view which is passed from  controller through view.
controlller.cs

```
var category = (from s in context.M_ProductCategory
                                where s.ID == C_ID
                                select s.Title);
 ViewBag.cat = category;
```

Index.cshtml

```
 @{  
        Html.RenderPartial("PartialViewSpecification", new { ProductCategory = @ViewBag.cat });  
    }
```

I need to use the value of ViewBag.cat in PartialViewSpecification.Please help

Comment: If your wanting to pass the model (i.e. `IEnumerable<M_ProductCategory>`) to the partial view, then it needs to be `Html.RenderPartial("PartialViewSpecification" ViewBag.cat)` and the partial view needs `@model IEnumerable<M_ProductCategory>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way:
Controller:

```
var category = (from s in context.M_ProductCategory
                                where s.ID == C_ID
                                select s.Title);
 ViewBag.cat = category.FirstOrDefault();
```

Index.cshtml:

```
@{
    Html.RenderPartial("PartialViewSpecification");
}
```

PartialViewSpecification.cshtml(partialView):

```
@ViewBag.cat
```

I hope this one is working...

Answer (score 0):

**Index.cshtml:**

```
@{
    Html.RenderPartial("PartialViewSpecification", (string)(ViewBag.cat)); 
}
```

**PartialViewSpecification.cshtml**:

```
@model string

<span>Model</span>
```